# maven-antrun-plugin copy resources works only on validate phase

Tags: maven, maven-antrun-plugin

I am using maven-antrun-plugin version 1.8 to copy some files to the src/main/resources folder so that it gets included in jar in package phase.

If the execution *phase* of the task defined to copy to resources folder is **validate** everything works fine but if it is **compile/test** the files are copied to src/main/resources folder but are not included in jar

Comment: Why are you copying them? Why not put them into src/main/resources?

Comment: I am trying to copy some external resources which are not within same project.

Comment: That sounds wrong, cause resources belong to the project which is using them...Furthermore If you have them in another project which not using the dependency to the jar which contains the resources so they are on the classpath ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because Resources folder gets copied to target folder at process-resources phase of Maven. Therefore to get files in the resources folder of jar/war you need to copy files to resources folder before the process-resources phase i.e. you can pick validate, initialize and generate-sources phase of maven for same.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to understand the [Maven lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html). Bind the Antrun plugin to an early enough phase to achieve what you want.

That said - consider packaging the other resources into a jar and then adding that jar as a dependency instead of adding Antrun plugin invocations. Or, use the Assembly plugin.